# Is there a Darboux function like the one described below?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exists [Darboux function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function) which is continuous at only one point and discontinuous at all other points in the interval on which it is defined?

Comment: Despite providing a link, your **Q.** is hard to interpret uniquely. I can't be sure what **you** mean. I'd welcome an explicit definition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Consider, for instance, [Conway's base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) $c$, or any function that is everywhere discontinuous and has range $\mathbb R$ in every interval. Pick continuous bijections $f_n:\mathbb R\to(-1/n,1/n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N^+$. Pick a strictly decreasing sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ converging to $0$.

Define $f$ by setting $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ or $\pm x_n$ for some $n$, $f(x)=c(x)$ if $x<-x_1$ or $x>x_1$ and, otherwise, $f(x)=f_n\circ c(x)$ for $x\in (-x_n,-x_{n+1})\cup(x_{n+1},x_n)$.

This function $f$ satisfies $f(x)\to 0=f(0)$ as $x\to 0$, and $f$ is discontinuous everywhere else, since $c$ is.